# How to programatically pass arguments to OnStart method of a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, timer

How do i programatically pass in arguments to OnStart method of a  Service, which I further need to propagate to the Elapsed event of the Timer inside the service?

Comment: Can you clarify, is this an existing installed service that you plan on starting from you program?  Or are you programming the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the simplest level: when you call `ServiceBase.Run`, you get to give it the service instances to execute. Simply declare this as a public property on your service, and assign prior to calling `Run`:

```
        Service1 myService = new Service1();
        myService.SomeProp = 1;
        ServiceBase.Run(myService);
```

Then read `SomeProp` in your service:

```
    public int SomeProp { get; set;}
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        int prop = SomeProp;
    }
```

You can also use the service args, but that is from the external caller (service registration) - not programatically (per the question).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having the OnStart method read the arguments from a configuration file and programatically update that, using either a separate application.